# A piece of C++17 code that is hard to read Template structure, and two template functions

Tags: c++, c++17

```
namespace Ubpa::USRefl {
   // [summary]
   // attribute for field, class, enum
   // [member]
   // T value (T == void -> no value)
   template<typename Name, typename T>
   struct Attr;

   template<typename Name>
   Attr(Name)->Attr<Name, void>;

   template<typename Name, typename Value>
   Attr(Name, Value)->Attr<Name, Value>;
}
```

I am a beginner from C++11. I hope someone can explain the meaning of the above code in an easy-to-understand manner.

Comment: Which parts of the code do you understand now, and what can we help you with? Can you provide some context on this code and what you’re aiming to do with it?

Comment: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: (I’m asking because there’s namespaces, templates, and template deduction guides here and I’m not sure which one you’d like help with. ^_^)

Comment: I  understand namespace nesting now namespace::Ubpa::USRefl
I don't understand what the definition of{ template<typename Name, typename T>  struct Attr} does.and Attr(Name)->Attr<Name, void>;

Comment: @Vigil `template<typename Name, typename T> struct Attr;` is just a declaration of a class template. The other declarations in the namespace are deduction guides as explained in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @user17732522 I still have one last confusion: struct attr; There is nothing in this structure. Is it meaningful to deduce its type?

Comment: @Vigil It is just a (forward-)declaration of the class template. The definition is somewhere else. (You are not showing it.)